# Getting "Error: Can't use $geoWithin with Array" from MongooseJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I execute the following kind of query with [MongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com):

```
Place
  .find({location:{$geoWithin:{$box:[[0, -40],[151.0983703,-33.8674744]]}}})
  .exec(function(err, places) {
    ...
  });
```

I get zero results and the following message returned in the `err`

> [Error: Can't use $geoWithin with Array.]

Yet if I execute the exact same criteria directly against MongoDB, on the command line:

```
> db.places.find({location:{$geoWithin:{$box:[[0, -40],[151.0983703,-33.8674744]]}}})
```

I get the correct list of records shown in the output.

What am I doing wrong with the MongooseJS code?

Comment: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1450

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try updating Mongoose and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$geoWithin` wasn't implemented in the version of Mongoose that I'm using.

My solution for the time being is to use the native mongodb library, until the stable build of Mongoose is updated with support for `$geoWithin`.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(app.get('mongodb connection string'), function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    db.collection('places')
        .find({location:{
            $geoWithin:{
                $box:[[Number(req.query.northEastLng), Number(req.query.northEastLat)], 
                      [Number(req.query.southWestLng), Number(req.query.southWestLat)]]}}})
        .toArray(function(err, results) {
            if (!results)
                results = [];

            res.render('nearbyplaces', {
                results: results
            });

            db.close();
        });
});
```

This works fine.

(Note: if you really want to use Mongoose, you could download the latest unstable build from their Github page. I'd just prefer not to, because it would complicate deployment of my app. I want to be able to download everything with just `npm install`).